# checkSelfPermission returning false even if Permission is granted

Tags: android, android-storage

So I've been sitting here for 4 hours now, scratching my head as to why are my 2 devices misbehaving.
The problem is, checkSelfPermission is returning false, even if the permission is granted!
I'm 100% sure that this shouldn't happen, as it worked as expected 5-6 days ago.
Here's the code I'm using to check if the permission is granted or not.

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("BaseActivity", "Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("BaseActivity", "Storage Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("BaseActivity", "Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now, whenever I open the activity (`BaseActivity`) which has this code for the first time, it works as expected and requests user for the Storage permission.
But, in the fragment which is in this activity, where I want to access the files, whenever I call this method, it has started returning false.
I've made this method public and it used to return true/false depending on the situation.
Here's how I check if permission is granted in Fragment.

```
if (!((BaseActivity) getActivity()).isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.storagePermissionError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
```

I'm on `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` 28, so scoped external storage permissions shouldn't be the problem. What am I doing wrong here? Why does `isStoragerPermissionGranted()` method always returning `false` even if I 100% have given STORAGE permission to my app?

Comment: Did you add those permissions in Manifest?

Comment: Also try to check manually where permission is granted or not using **Settings->Apps->"Your_APP"->Permissions**

Comment: `if (!((BaseActivity) getActivity()).isStoragePermissionGranted()` Strange construct. Make the function static and call it like `if (!BaseActivity.isStoragePermissionGranted(getActivity())`.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Yes I've added those permissions in Manifest and I' manually checked if the permission was granted in the app settings.

Comment: @blackapps I cannot make the function static because checkSelfPermission isn't a static function. It cannot be referenced from static context. As I said, this worked as expected before 3-4 days, and it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Of courdse it can be made static. You gave the isStoragePermissionGranted(Activity activity) an Activity parameter. So then you can call checkSelfPermission() on the activity parameter. `activity.checkSelfPermission()`.

Comment: @blackapps Tried doing that, still doesn't work.

Comment: @blackapps I found the answer, it was an SDK from the app which set the tag maxSdkVersion for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found what was wrong with the app.
The problem was Vungle ads SDK, which set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

And according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element#maxSdk the system wouldn't grant `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission even if it was directly set in the Settings itself.

So this SDK set this tag, and it was pretty hard to find because it was inside **Merged Manifest** where I was able to luckily spot this thing.

To overcome this problem without removing the SDK from your app, do the following thing:
Add `tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"`

So it becomes like this:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

to the tag which has `maxSdkVersion` set in your own `Manifest.xml`.

Comment: god bless you man

Answer (score -1):

After trying many things, this approach is working fine for me

```
public boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Permission array

```
 private String[] permissions = (new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE});
```

If call

```
    if (hasPermissions(this, permissions)) {
        Intent intent = getPickIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
```